# Java String function can not be called because it's not static

Tags: java, string, methods, static-methods

Let me explain further. I have a String function (called stringReversal) that returns a reversed string, it has no errors in the function. But, when I try to print using `System.out.println()` from the main function, it gives me the error "Can not make a static reference to the non static method stringReversal (string s) from the type StringReverse".

I tried giving my stringReversal a `static` modifier, but after doing so, it gave me run time errors.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
public class StringReverse {

    public String stringReversal(String s){

        if(s == null){
            return null;
        }

        else if(s.length()% 2 == 0){
            int size = s.length();

            for(int i =0; i<s.length(); i++){
                s.replace(s.charAt(i), s.charAt(size));
                size--;
                if(i == (s.length()/2) || size==0)
                    break;
            }
        }

        else{
            for(int i =0; i<s.length(); i++){
                int size = s.length();

                s.replace(s.charAt(i), s.charAt(size));
                size--;

                if(i == ((s.length()/2) +1) || size==0 )
                    break;
            }
        }

        return s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Hello";
        String rev = stringReversal(str);

        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: What run-time errors are you getting?

Comment: @VinceEmigh it doesn't compile. The OP posted his/her error.

Comment: I'm still downvoting though. @Ebad did you google your error message and follow any advice you got, *before* posting to StackOverflow?

Comment: You must make the *method* `static`.  Runtime errors would be unrelated to this.

Comment: Those are compile errors. Run time errors is when your app crashes.

Comment: This is a lot of (completely broken) code for no reason. What's wrong with `new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString()`?

Comment: @VinceEmigh sorry - didn't realize OP used that phrase. (Incorrectly, as I'm sure you realized.)

Comment: Let me guess -- After making the method static you got this runtime error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String ind
ex out of range: 5 
        at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
        at StringReverse.stringReversal(StringReverse.java:24)
        at StringReverse.main(StringReverse.java:37)` ---- You know, the thing to do is to actually report what that error is, vs saying "I got an error".

Comment: @HotLicks, that is what I got, apologies for the confusing I created by not copying and pasting it.

Comment: Basically, your problem is this: `int size = s.length(); s.replace(s.charAt(i), s.charAt(size));`.  "size" here will be the length of `s`, and `charAt` must be passed a parm between 0 and size-1.  So it will inevitably get an error.  (It's easy to tell what the error is, of course, because the above exception message gives you the method (`charAt`) and where it was called (`stringReversal` at line 24).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to instantiate your class to call object members, or you need to make your function static, indicating it's not part of object oriented paradigm

In your case you can do

```
StringReverse sr = new StringReverse();
String rev = sr.stringReversal("hello");
```

or declare your method differently

```
public static String stringReversal(String s)
```

In fact the class name StringReverse itself does not sound like some kind of object, so the second way is preferred impo

The deeper problem you have is the confusion on how Java handle OO and entrance function in general. Java is primarily an OO language so most of the time everything shall be an object or a member of a object. But when you telling the VM to run some java code, there got to be a place to start, which is the main method. There has to be one main method and it must be under some class, but it really has nothing to do with the class that contains it. Within the main method, you either start your OO life by instantiating objects and invoking their members (method 1) or stay in the spaghetti world for a bit longer, by calling other static members as procedures (method 2).

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Keep the method non `static` and then create an instance of your class to call the method:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       String str = "Hello";

       StringReverse sr = new StringReverse(); // instance of class
       String rev = sr.stringReversal(str);

       System.out.println(); // just prints a blank line lol...
   }
   ```
2. Make the method `static` (you should do this):

   ```
   public static String stringReversal(String s) {
       // ...
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       String str = "Hello";
       String rev = stringReversal(str);

       System.out.println(); // just prints a blank line lol...
   }
   ```

Either way, you have to fix your "run time errors". You can't get around that. If your method doesn't work, keeping it not `static` won't make it work either.

By the way, I think you meant to do `System.out.println(rev);` instead of `System.out.println();`

---

For the record, here is how to easily reverse a string (both methods work):

```
public static String stringReversal(String s) {

    StringBuffer reverseString = new StringBuffer();

    // reverse the string
    for (int i = s.length() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        reverseString.append(s.charAt(i));
    }

    return reverseString.toString();
}

/* using the reverse() method in the StringBuffer class
   instead of reversing the string through iterations */
public static String stringReversal2(String s) {
    return new StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your Main method is static, but the class that it's in is not. In order to call a non-static method, you need to create an instance of the class. Alternatively, the method can be made static, but in order to refer to it you need to include the class name in your call (as if to use the class itself like an object containing the method - see below).

There are three solutions to this problem:

- Make an instance of the class and call the method from your object *(recommended)*.
- make the method static and use StringReverse.stringReversal().
- Make the class AND the method static.

Comment: @dognose yes it is. please explain.

Comment: @djechlin static Main Method is convention. But you dont turn your whole application into "static calls", just because your main method is static. Ever heard of Application Instances?

Comment: It's an "outer" class -- you can't make it `static`.

Comment: @dognose you're right that just because main is static doesn't mean the methods should be. But this should be static anyway. If I were writing this as part of a package I would make definitely make it static, since it requires no internal state to work and shouldn't require the memory or lines of code to make an object. In fact [Apache's StringUtils.reverse](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#reverse(java.lang.String)) is static.

Comment: @djechlin About the context of THIS method you are right. But since TC does have trouble calling a non static method from within Main Method, the simple solution "make method static" seems too broad to me.

Comment: @dognose as a *very* broad rule of thumb with many exceptions, I would say methods should be static when they can be. If, however, the OP had this problem on variables instead of on methods, it would be just as likely that those should indeed be instance variables and main should instantiate an object. In any case I'm guessing this is far over the OP's head...  and just going with static is the right thing to do around chapter 3 of an intro Java book.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason for this method to not be static, since it references nothing in the containing class.

Comment: I think, "we" all know, when a method can be static, and when not. My Concerns are just about the issue "calling method from (static) Main() does not work" - and the Answer "Make method static" (TC might think, that he has no other choice, than using static methods)

Comment: Changed the order of the items in the list, and added recommended beside the instantiate solution.